# Как писать названия оружия?

Tags: орфография, прописная-строчная, кавычки, названия, аббревиатуры

Как правильно писать в художественном тексте названия/марки оружия?
Как правильно писать сокращённые названия: с большой буквы, с маленькой, в кавычках или без?

**1.** *В кобуре у него лежал верный Кольт.* ("Кольт", кольт или "кольт"?)
**2.** *Со своим надёжным ТОЗ-ом он пошёл на охоту.* (Или ТОЗом?)
**3.** *Охотник Винчестер пропил.* ("Винчестер", винчестер или "винчестер"? Речь идет о ружье, а не о классе оружия.)
**4.** *Любимую Беретту он подарил своему внуку.* ("Беретту", беретту или "беретту"?)

Comment: • Тульский оружейный завод (ТОЗ) никак не относится к зарубежным производителям, поэтому я исправлю вашу шапку (ну и заодно — всё остальное; надеюсь, вы не против). • Есть и другие названия у этого оружия: *мелкашка, тозовка*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. > **3.** Не выделяются кавычками:
   > **1)** наименования производственных изделий, ставшие общеупотребительными названиями: *браунинг, наган, галифе, макинтош, френч*...
2. При склонении аббревиатурных названий дефис не употребляется, а окончание нужного падежа добавляется к аббревиатуре строчными буквами без пробела:
   *по ГОСТу, во МХАТе, у МАЗа, **ТОЗом**.*
3. Думаю, что *кольт* и *винчестер* известны многим, поэтому считаю, что в художественном тексте их можно писать со строчной буквы и без кавычек.
   А вот *беретта* менее распространена, и в текстах ее чаще всего обрамляют кавычками.
4. Примеры из Нацкорпуса

*На ремне висел порыжевший от ржавчины отцовский **винчестер*** (Юрий Рытхэу. Самые красивые корабли).
*Он выхватил старенький ветеранский **кольт**, выстрелил навскидку* (Александр Силаев. Армия Гутэнтака).
*Взяв три итальянские **«беретты»** с глушителями, любезно предоставленные Гариком, который не испытывал в Европе дефицита оружия, друзья отправились по указанному адресу* (Андрей Ростовский. По законам волчьей стаи).
*Причем это не игрушки, а настоящие **кольты, вальтеры, беретты**, пулевые или газовые, к ним боезапас — патроны, баллончики* (А. Е. Рекемчук. Мамонты).

[§ 62. Названия марок машин, производственных изделий и т. д.](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=169#pp169) (Розенталь)
[Как правильно употреблять аббревиатуры?](https://gramota.ru/biblioteka/spravochniki/pismovnik/kak-pravilno-upotreblyat-abbreviatury) ("Грамота")
[Беретта](https://ruscorpora.ru/results?search=Cs8BEqIBCp8BChMKCWRpc2FtYm1vZBIGCgRtYWluChcKB2Rpc3Rtb2QSDAoKd2l0aF96ZXJvcxJvChcKA2xleBIQCg7QsdC10YDQtdGC0YLQsAoKCgRmb3JtEgIKAAoLCgVncmFtbRICCgAKCQoDc2VtEgIKAAoVCgdzZW0tbW9kEgoKCHNlbXxzZW14CgwKBnN5bnRheBICCgAKCwoFZmxhZ3MSAgoAKiEKCAgAEAoYMiAKEAUgACi44LuQq8jaCUAFagQwLjk1eAAyAggBOgEBMAE=) (Нацкорпус)

Answer (score 4):

[Справка:](https://gramota.ru/spravka/vopros/234170#question)

> Верно написание: пистолет «Оса», пистолет «Стрела», винтовка «Сайга»,
> так как эти названия являются условными. Слова браунинг, наган, кольт
> и пр. пишутся со строчной буквы, если имеются в виду виды оружия, и с
> прописной, если имеются в виду фамилии конструкторов.

*Охотник винчестер пропил.*

*Любимую беретту он подарил своему внуку.*

*Со своим надёжным ТОЗом он пошёл на охоту.*

> ТОЗ — Тульский оружейный завод и его изделия: ТОЗ-8 — однозарядная
> малокалиберная спортивная винтовка ТОЗ-12 — однозарядная
> малокалиберная спортивная винтовка ТОЗ-16 — охотничий однозарядный
> малокалиберный карабин.